# PHP - pass line number automatically as function argument

Tags: php

I am writing Logger class in PHP. Is there a way, how to automatically pass line number and script file from call?

Sample:

```
Logger::Log("message", __LINE__, __FILE__)
```

I want to  pass `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` automatically, without need of writing it. I have tried to make

```
public static function Log($msg, $l = __LINE__, $f = __FILE__) { ... }
```

but this pass line number and file of `Log` method. Is this even possible in PHP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`debug_backtrace`](http://php.net/debug_backtrace) inside of `Logger::Log` to retrieve a call stack, which includes the file and line number of the code that called `Logger::Log`. That's a sensible thing to include in loggers in general.